# PHP/html Get li's content

Tags: php, html, forms, html-lists

I want to get `<li>` values from a form. I named all my `<li>` with the same name, only the value is changing (i want to get this value). Im using post method but when i try to read the posted content, only the latest `<li>` is sent no matter which `<li>` i clicked:

```
<form method = "post" action ="{{path('recap')}}">
<ul>
  <li onclick="submit()"><input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar"><a href="#">bar</a></li>
  <li onclick="submit()"><input type="hidden" name="foo" value="barfoo"><a href="#">barfoo</a></li>
  <li onclick="submit()"><input type="hidden" name="foo" value="foofoobar"><a href="#">foofoobar</a></li>           
</ul>
</form>
```

Here only "foofoobar" is sent.  I tried to name all my `<li>` like "foo[]" and dump it. I've seen that all were sent by post at the same time. This is why i can only read the last one.

I don't want to use GET method

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Why should anything else get sent? Your inputs ALL have the same name, so only the last one will actually take effect.

Comment: Why not use <select>?

Comment: Normal people would use `<input type="submit" name="foo" value="bar" />` - only the button that is clicked gets sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an input that will only be a successful control when you click on it. i.e. a submit button.

That will remove the need to have JavaScript to submit the form and a link to the top of the page to provide something visible to click on.

```
<form>
<ul>
    <li> <input type="submit" name="foo" value="bar">
    <li> <input type="submit" name="foo" value="barfoo">
    <li> <input type="submit" name="foo" value="foofoobar">
</ul>
</form>
```

Add CSS to remove the default background and borders if you don't like the look of the submit buttons (or don't since the default styling makes it something obviously clickable).